# Disable Transformation from background on modal open

Tags: react-native

Am I able to disable the transform from the background, while open a modal?

```js
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        onRequestClose={() => openBottomSheet(false)}
        transparent
        style={{
          flex: 1,
        }}
        presentationStyle="pageSheet"
        visible={bottomSheetOpen}>
        <View
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderRadius: 16,
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
          }}>
          <DatepickerBottomSheet />
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

The background should stay on the same position and not zoom out, it should look like a bottomSheet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this `presentationStyle="overFullScreen"`

Docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#presentationstyle-ios